# Retain selected state when dragging in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I just like to ask if it is possible to retain the selected state of a button when I drag my fingers to other position. Currently, the button goes back to its normal state if I loose touch on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this isn't a good practice. Button states are meant to show the touch's interaction with the button, so this might complicate thing later. Buttons usually get activated when the touch is released over them, (unlike mouse-controlled apps) so the default behavior is to return to normal state when the touch moves out of the button.

Anyway, you can override the touch events (touchsesMove and TouchesEnd or selected/unselected) and manage the button's state or sprite bitmaps

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will consider your suggestion